# React div style not updating on render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the background color of a div when an array in my context is populated. On the initial render the background is being set as I would expect, however when the context is updated and a new value is pushed into the array, I can see the length increasing in the  tags, however the background color set in the style doesn't seem to update.

Code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Consumer } from '../../context';

import AlertWindow from './AlertWindow';

class AlertTab extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            type: props.type,
            active_color: props.active_color
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Consumer>
                {value => {
                    const { geofence_alarms } = value;
                    const { type, active_color } = this.state;

                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className='alert-tab' style={{background: (geofence_alarms.length > 0 ? active_color : '#8E8E8E')}}>
                                <h6>{type}</h6>
                                <h6 style={{fontSize:'22pt', float: 'right'}}>{geofence_alarms.length}</h6>
                            </div>
                            <AlertWindow />
                        </div>
                    )
                }}
            </Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default AlertTab;
```

You can see from the below images that the length of the *geofence_alerts* array does indeed increase:

[image: geofence_alerts length increasing]

I'm assuming this has something to do with the way styles are being loaded in React, but does anyone know the proper way I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, don't use `this.state` for props. When properties update, a rerender will happen, but the component will not be reinitialized/remounted. Since you copy over your props to the state in the constructor, this will not be called, and your state will contain the old props that were passed in initially when the component was mounted. In this case, you can pull `type` and `active_color` straight from `this.props`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Consumer } from '../../context';

import AlertWindow from './AlertWindow';

class AlertTab extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Consumer>
                {value => {
                    const { geofence_alarms } = value;
                    const { type, active_color } = this.props;

                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className='alert-tab' style={{background: (geofence_alarms.length > 0 ? active_color : '#8E8E8E')}}>
                                <h6>{type}</h6>
                                <h6 style={{fontSize:'22pt', float: 'right'}}>{geofence_alarms.length}</h6>
                            </div>
                            <AlertWindow />
                        </div>
                    )
                }}
            </Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default AlertTab;
```

Comment: Also, `console.log(active_color)`. Perhaps it needs a `#` prepended to it?

Comment: Hi @FrankerZ I tried using props instead of state but still not updating the div background. The active_color prop/state is not changing after the initial render anyhow, its the inline if statement within the style which should specify between using the two colors. Any ideas?

Comment: Log the active_color as I've stated above, and post an update. I have an inkling suspicion that you need to prepend a `#` to active_color (ie. `geofence_alarms.length > 0 ? '#' + active_color : '#8E8E8E'`)

Comment: spot on with the `#`, can't believe I missed that.. Many thanks for your help!